# Does hibernate always need add/ clear method when @OneToMany annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lord", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Getter
private Set<Planet> planets;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "lord_id")
private Lord lord;
```

For example
Lord have two planets and i wanna detach this two planets of this lord

I select lord joining planet table and then i clear planets this way fetchedLordById.clearPlanets(); & repo.save(fetchedLordById);

```
// Lord code above
public void clearPlanets() {
    this.planets.forEach(item -> item.setLord(null));
    this.planets.clear();
}
```

is this a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

From the [Hibernate ORM documentation about one-to-many bidirectional associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional):

> Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application
> developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

So what you are doing is correct.

You have also the possibility to enable [bytecode enhancements](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-enhancement) for [bidirectional associations management](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-dirty-tracking-bidirectional):

```
hibernate.enhancer.enableAssociationManagement = true
```

When this property is enabled you will only need to update one side of the associations. Just keep in mind that if you enable it, you might also need to update your code to work with it because it changes how Hibernate ORM deals with associations.